# MATLAB: How to store clicked coordinates (peakpoints) continuosly from time series plot even after panning etc.

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am currently working on a matlab GUI where I need to click unwanted peak points (not to delete them) and store their results in a matrix (continuously). I am using a pushbutton with the following code to collect the points and store results. However, when I clicked the points only the last clicked results stores (not all the clicked points). Also, since it is a continuous plot I am using a PAN pushbutton to move the data. Hence, I would like to do the following:

1)For a pushbutton click (to collect peaks from getpts function) I want to click and collect several points (store and append the values continuously for each click). Also, I want the array to be active even after I use the PAN button to move the plot. 
2) I want to create another pushbutton to end the task (asking the user to "do you want to stop collecting the peak points", stop collecting the points and store the entire clicked results in an array)

```
axes(handles.axes1);
[ptsx1,ptsy1] = getpts(gcf);
idx = knnsearch([t',fbsum],[ptsx1 ptsy1],'k',1)
if evalin('caller', 'exist(''xArray'',''var'')')
  xArray = evalin('caller','xArray');
 else 
  xArray = [];
 end
 xArray = [xArray; idx] %
 assignin('caller','xArray',xArray); `% save to base`
 save('xArray.mat','xArray');
```

Sorry, this is my first post and please accept my apology and please clarify if something is not clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would use `setappdata` and `getappdata` within the GUI to store and retrieve your results matrix.

Comment: Hi Matt thanks, I will look into the above two commands. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: Using a GUIDE based GUI Instead**

In Matlab command window define your X & Y

```
>> x = 0:.1:4*pi;
>> y = sin(x);
>> y(10:10:end) = 2; %With some bad points to mark
```

Then run the GUI, select Start Marking, mark some points Pan around etc.:

```
>> plotTest(x,y)
```

After exiting the GUI look at the globla IDX_STORE:

```
>> global IDX_STORE
>> IDX_STORE

IDX_STORE =

    10    30    40
```

If you want the x , y values marked then it is just

```
>> markedX = x(IDX_STORE);
>> markedY = y(IDX_STORE);
```

The GUI is laid out Like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnKNR.png).

**GUI Code Looks like this:**

```
function varargout = plotTest(varargin)
% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',mfilename,'gui_Singleton',gui_Singleton,'gui_OpeningFcn', @plotTest_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @plotTest_OutputFcn,'gui_LayoutFcn',[] ,'gui_Callback',[]);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end
if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT

% --- Executes just before plotTest is made visible.
function plotTest_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
global IDX_STORE
IDX_STORE = [];
handles.output = [];
if numel(varargin) ~= 2
    handles.closeFigure = true;
else    
    x = varargin{1}; y =varargin{2};
    handles.l = plot(handles.axes1,x,y);
    hold(handles.axes1,'on')
    handles.axes1.ButtonDownFcn = {@clickCallback,handles};
    handles.l.ButtonDownFcn     = {@clickCallback,handles};
    guidata(hObject, handles);
end

% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = plotTest_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
varargout{1} = [];
if (isfield(handles,'closeFigure') && handles.closeFigure)
    errordlg('Nothing Passed in!')    
end

% --- Executes on button press in markToggle.
function markToggle_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
switch handles.markToggle.Value
    case 1
        handles.markToggle.String = 'Stop Marking';
    case 0
        handles.markToggle.String = 'Start Marking';        
end

function clickCallback(hObj,evtData,handles)
global IDX_STORE
if handles.markToggle.Value == 0
    return %Do Nothing if toggle not pressed.
end
coordinates = handles.axes1.CurrentPoint(1,1:2); %Get coordinates of mouse click
idx = knnsearch([handles.l.XData' handles.l.YData'],coordinates);%Find closest point in line data
IDX_STORE = unique([IDX_STORE idx]); %Store the index.   
mH = findobj(handles.axes1,'tag','markLine');%Add some markers to see what you are doing.
if isempty(mH) %Make the marker plot if it doesn't exist
    plot(handles.axes1, handles.l.XData(IDX_STORE),handles.l.YData(IDX_STORE),'rO','tag','markLine')
else%If it does exist then update the markers
    mH.XData = handles.l.XData(IDX_STORE);    mH.YData = handles.l.YData(IDX_STORE);
end
guidata(hObj,handles); %Save handles structure
```

Comment: Dear Aero Engy (sorry could not find your real name), thanks for the quick answer. Just now I tested it works fine. I will test it for few more data and then accept your answer. Also, is it possible to get the X and Y co-ordinates of the clicked points? Also, I am bit confused about turning off zoom and PAN buttons (At this stage I am using pushbutton. Do you think toggle will help me to achieve this). Sorry, to ask you too many questions. It was of great help, much appreciated. Regards

Comment: The coordinate of the marked points are just your original x and y at the indices that get stored in the global variable.  I can edit the answer tomorrow if you are still confused.  What i mean by turning pan/zoom off.  Is that if you use pan to scroll to a new region of the plot you wont be able to click more poimts until you turn pan back off.

Comment: Dear Aero Engy, thanks. Edited answer would be great. Also, I will try to implement the same in my current GUI and will get back to you for any further doubts. Thanks for helping me with this. Regards

Comment: Dear Aero Engy, I tried to impliment the same application in matlab GUI using guide but I get an error related to struct:"Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there were 2 results." Could you please guide me how can I implement this in my matlab GUI using a toggle button. Thanks and regards

Comment: Add edited the answer into a simple GUI.  If that helps then please upvote accept the answer.

Comment: Dear Aero Engy, thanks for your answer. I will upvote (accept) the answer soon. Regards

Comment: Dear Aero Engy, I have accepted this answer. While trying to implement the same in my GUI I am facing some issues. I already have GUI figure with lots of pushbuttons and others. I created a toggle button (which can do start and stop to collect the points) but bit confused which part of the code (your code) I need to modify etc. I will keep trying. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If you can post the code somewhere online I can take a look when I have time.  Here might not be the best place if it is really long.  Maybe pastebin?  Or a shared google doc.

Comment: Dear Aero Engy, could you please share your email id? If not I will provide mine and you can share your id there. I will then send the code across. Thanks

Comment: It is AeroEngy then at Outlook  ... i dont like writing it out completely because it keeps scraped up by spam bots.  But I think you get the idea

Comment: Dear AeroEngy, i have sent an email to you with all the information. Thanks and regards

Comment: Dear AeroEngy did you receive my email? Kindly let me know.

Comment: Yes,  out of town this weekend.  Ill take a look tomorrow

Comment: Thanks, I will wait for your response

Comment: Check your email :)

Comment: Hi AeroEngy, thanks I have sent an email with my code for you to look at it. Regards